# Change uib-modal size dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was wondering the best way, if possible to change the size of a uibootsrap modal on the fly. I have implemented a paging of sorts where within the same modal body, if the user presses a 'next' button in the footer of the modal, it will load in another template, like so:

```
<div id="rule-values-page"
    ng-show="rcw.page ==='Rule Values'">

    <first-template-values ng-show="rcw.provider=== 'First Template'"
        rule-fields="rcw.fields"></first-template-values>

    <second-template-values ng-show="rcw.provider === 'Second Template'"
        rule-fields="rcw.fields"></second-template-values>

    <third-template-values ng-show="rcw.provider=== 'Third Template'"
        rule-fields="rcw.fields"></third-template-values>

</div>
```

There is some JavaScript behind the scenes that determines what happens when the next button is clicked (above is just an approximation of what it looks like).
When I launch the original modal that contains a previous page which leads to this one, I use

```
var ruleModalTemplate = {
        templateUrl: 'app/indicator/rule-create-wizard.html',
        backdrop: 'static',
        controller: 'ruleCreateWizard',
        controllerAs: 'rcw',
        windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
        resolve: {
          ruleCreateWizardControllerInput: function() {
            return {
              name: vm.name,
              desc: vm.description
            };
          }
        }
      };
```

The key here being `windowClass` as you can set the size to whatever you want there `sm`, `lg`, or custom like I have. Now the issue I have is the size is okay for some of the subsequent pages, but looks silly for other pages. I want to be able to control the size whenever. Would this be done by applying an `ng-class` or something to the modal body? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** So I went down the `ng-class` route and am having some trouble. I tried to apply the `ng-class` to the template being called from the previous directive `'app/indicator/rule-create-wizard.html'` like so:

```
<div id="rule-create-wizard"
    ng-form="ruleFormMaster"
    ng-class="rcw.modalSize()">
    ...
</div>
```

and let the decision of what class to be applied to in the method `modalSize()` method which looks as :

```
function modalSize() {
  switch (vm.page) {
    case 'Rule Provider Selection':
      return 'app-modal-window-sm';
      break;
    case 'Rule Selection':
      console.debug('in rule selection modal size method');
      return 'app-modal-window-lg';
      break;
  }
}
```

just returning the string of the css class :

```
.app-modal-window-lg .modal-dialog {
  width: 65%;
}

.app-modal-window-sm .modal-dialog {
  width: 20%;
}
```

The issue is that it isn't applying it to the modal, because the directive for the modal doesn't actually have access (i believe) to the root instance of the html of the modal. See picture below:

[image]

It is applying it I correctly (though not where I thought) to the template, but not the actual modal. If I were to use the default values for uibootstrap inside of the calling directive `windowClass: sm` etc that appears in the correct location (blue arrow in the pic) but not in the highlighted location.

Still looking for input - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some comparison to some regular bootstrap (non-angular) modal questions, I found using jquery provided a simple solution. Might not be the most optimized but works for the use case.

*Also keep in mind, if you are looking for a similar this isn't necessarily the best (if good at all) ux, just fit the requirements I was working with.*

Anyways, I passed in a dummy class that was for sure to be unique into the `windowClass` parameter of the uib-modal - in my case `app-dummy` as well as my initial class in which I wanted to apply to the modal `app-modal-window-md`:

```
  var ruleModalTemplate = {
    templateUrl: 'app/indicator/rule-create-wizard.html',
    backdrop: 'static',
    controller: 'ruleCreateWizard',
    controllerAs: 'rcw',
    windowClass: 'app-dummy app-modal-window-md',
    resolve: {
      ruleCreateWizardControllerInput: function() {
        return {
          name: vm.name,
          desc: vm.description
        };
      }
    }
  };
```

Then I created a `resize()` method which would get called during the page changes inside of the modal:

```
function resize() {
  switch (vm.page) {
    case 'Rule Provider Selection':
      $('.app-dummy .modal-dialog ')
        .css({
          'width': '30%'
        });
      break;
    case 'Rule Selection':
      var test = $('.app-dummy .modal-dialog ')
        .css({
          'width': '40%'
        });
      break;
    case 'Rule Values':
      $('.app-dummy .modal-dialog')
        .css({ 'width': '70%' })
      break;
  }
}
```

The JQuery targets the `app-dummy` class each time on page change and depending on the page will apply the width. My needs weren't too complex so this could be more robust, but for the question being asked this was my solution.